# Custom 404 page not executing for missing ASPX pages - IIS 7,5

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, error-handling, web-config

Using IIS 7.5 in classic mode (as we're using SiteCore) with a WebForms app (.Net 3.5), we have error pages defined as

```
  <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
    <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
    <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/Error/404.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
  </httpErrors>
```

Now, for files of a non .Net type that aren't found when requested , the custom error page isn't being displayed, and a standard 404 status type is returned. If we use a custom error page with a .htm extension (e.g. path="/Error/404.htm"), then it is displayed!

From what I've read the  xml is correct, and should work for non .Net file types. I have no  section in my web.config. Sounds like something else e.g. SiteCore maybe affecting things - let me know if you need any more info.

Answer (score 1):

404 custom page - works .aspx & non .aspx URLs
Works on GoDaddy Shared Windows Hosting (IIS7 .Net4)

Create a 404.html or 404.aspx file on your local main folder in your shared GoDaddy hosting.

-Web.Config File-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
         <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Main Rule" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="404.html or 404.aspx" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding this 404 page to IIS -> Website properties -> Custom Errors tab, then under 404, point to the web page that you would like to show up when a file is not found?